# ejs/html not finding external js file (node js)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

```
--public/javascripts/myscript.js

--views/index.ejs
```

No matter what I do, or what variation I use (ie declaring including `type="text/javascript"`) it wont find my external js file. I am using *node js* and I was told I may have to do something with routing, but that doesn't seem to be working either.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
   <!-- <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />-->

  </head>
  <body>

  <%include templates/header.ejs %>

  <script type="text/javascript" src=".../public/javascripts/myscript.js"> </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

I understand using routing in other `.js` files but not importing into html.

Also is there a better/neater was of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you base directory for adding static file, start from `public` 
ex.
your project directory
`/var/www/project/`
your assets located on
`/var/www/project/public/javascripts`
then you attach theme as bellow

```
//app.js
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

and on views you can do as bellow

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/myscript.js"> </script>
```